# What are the values of the parameters that make the function differentiable at zero?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I think I might have found a way to solve this problem but I'm not sure if this is correct, if someone could tell me if this is the correct approach or not that would be nice. If it's not the correct approach, can you tell me what approach I should take?

The problem is to find the values of "$a$" and "$b$" such that the following function is differentiable at $x=0$.

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
a\sin(2x)-4~~if~~x<0\\ 
b(x-1)+e^x~~if~~x\geq 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The approach that I took was to use the formal definition of a derivative, which is $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)+f(x)}{h}$ and finding a value for a and b such that the following two limits exist and equal each other (after setting $x=0$)

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{asin(2h)-8}{h}$$
and
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b(h-1)+e^h+b+1}{h}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a correct approach, but note that $f(0)=-b+1$, for which your limits should be
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a\sin(2h)-4-(1-b)}{h}\\
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{b(h-1)+e^h+b-1}{h}
$$
Instead of what you have wrote.
Also, you may want to use that the function must be continuous in order to be differentiable.